# IEnumerable - CopyToDataTable() Not Display

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am using LINQ and I want to put the result into `DataTable`

this is a simple code...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var qu = from p in DBop.SampleTBLs
          select p;
dt= qu.///// why i am not getting CopyToDataTable here ?
```

What is the wrong in my code?

Comment: What is the type of `qu` exactly?

Comment: Using for namespace System.Data.DataTableExtensions specified?

Comment: you 're missing DataTable.AsEnumerable()

Comment: Avicena00  can you explain to me ...

Comment: Rand Random.. I am using .. system.Data

Comment: Wait, you are using linq and you want to put the results in a `DataTable`?!? As a metaphor, I'm driving a car and I want to bridle horses to the front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Extension-Method `DataTableExtensions` Extend Generic `IEnumerable<T>` where `Base-Class` of `T` is `DataRow`. so Definition:

```
public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source ...)
                                           where T : DataRow
```

Your query probably return IEnumerable of different type than the DataRow.

But you can manualy export to DataTable like this:

```
//Create & Configure DataTable
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name Column", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Name Column", typeof(int));

//Your IEnumerable Query 
var qu = from p in DBop.SampleTBLs
         select new object[] {p.SomeProperty, p.SomeProperty2};

//Add results to DataTable
foreach (var item in qu)
    dt.Rows.Add(item);
```

---

### EDIT:

[How to: Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your answer ... but it didn't work ,, still CopyToDataTble() , not appear

Comment: and i get this error : Error 2 A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions' is a type not a namespace

Answer (score 1):

You are likely missing the reference to the assembly the class resides in. If we check the MSDN page for [`CopyToDataTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) we see at the top of the page the following

> **Namespace**:  System.Data
>   **Assembly**:  System.Data.DataSetExtensions (in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll)

So that means you need to have `using System.Data;` at the top of the file, but you also need to make sure you have `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` included in your [project references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx).

Some other things that would make it not show up: `DataSetExtensions` is new to .NET 3.5 so if you are building against 2.0 it also won't show up. Also `qu` must be a class that is covariant with `IEnumerable<DataRow>`, if `qu` does not fit the extension method will now show up.

Comment: thank you for your time ... i checked i am using System.Data; , and i checked the reference of my project it include   System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll  , i am using .NET 4.0

Comment: So that rules out everything execpt that `qu` is not a `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. If you mouse over the `var` what does it say the data type is?